# UICollectionViewCell shadow causes small lag

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

When scrolling down in my UICollectionView it lags, and caused by this:

```
imageCell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
imageCell?.layer.masksToBounds = false
imageCell?.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
imageCell?.layer.shadowRadius = 5.0
imageCell?.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeZero
imageCell?.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.grayColor().CGColor
```

imageCell is the cell name:

```
let imageCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("imageCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? CollectionViewCell
```

Any suggestions what i should do?

Comment: Did you create a cell in Interface Builder with a identifier of imageCell or is it all done in code?

Comment: @Jay The cell is created in Interface Builder, yes.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I ran into the similar issue

Comment: @JayVDiyk I removed the shadow. Looks more professional without shadow also.

Answer (score 1):

When using shadows, it is a good idea to specify the `shadowPath` if you know the shape.

```
imageCell?.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: imageCell?.frame ?? CGRectZero).CGPath
```

[Apple mentions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CALayer/shadowPath)

> Specifying an explicit path usually improves rendering performance.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same thing when I was using images that were too big. I converted then to .png and made them smaller - that helped. (not sure if you are using any images).

But the thing that really made  a difference was rasterizing

[cell.layer.shouldRasterize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18460655/uicollectionview-scrolling-choppy-when-loading-cells)