# How to load all cells of UICollectionView at once?

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview, cells

I have a `UICollectionView` with a lot of cells. I want to load all the cells in `viewDidLoad`, but `UICollectionView` loads its cells only when they are visible.

Any suggestions?

Comment: That is not the idea behind the collection view, you might just want to use normal `UIView` objects in a `UIScrollView`.

Comment: Can you provide a reason why you would want to not leverage cell reuse?

Comment: The not instanced images make lag on scrolling.

Comment: I think this is a great question and people that thumbed this down are straight up rude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To restate the problem, the collection view cells contain images that are loaded lazily, but you require that they appear immediately.  The idea behind your question is to force the collection view to preload all of it's cells. But you don't really want the cells, you want the images, so let's get the images.

The question doesn't contain much detail about where the images are, or the model, or your method of loading them in the datasource method, so here's an outline of the advice (which I can edit to be more specific if you post more specifics):

For local images, instantiated via `imageNamed:`, create a dictionary whose keys are the image names, and whose values are the instantiated images, build this dictionary before the collection view displays, then use the dictionary in the datasource method.

For remote images, your collection view datasource must fetch these asynchronously.  [I gave an answer here that covers this in detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15799432/poor-uicollectionview-scrolling-performance-with-uiimage/15799771#15799771).

In any case, @CrimsonChris was right to be skeptical about pre-loading the cells.  His answer, in my opinion, is ill-advised.  (I think he thinks so, too, but was trying to offer an answer to the question as written).

Comment: Thanks for answer, it's exactly my problem. The images are local.
I will studying your link :)

Answer (score 2):

Create the cells in `viewDidLoad` and put them in an array or dictionary. Then return the right one in `cellForItemAtIndexPath:`. This approach will NOT leverage cell reuse and may use a large amount of memory. However, it may scroll slightly smoother because the cells don't need to be setup on scroll.

Comment: @MrMojoRisin, I think this is a good answer to the question as-asked, but the question asks for something that shouldn't be done.  So the answer advises something that shouldn't be done.

Comment: I was hoping my answer would be interpreted as "don't do it this way".